# Symbol names convention in libstdc++

Tags: c++, symbols, libstdc++

During building a library I got the following "undefined reference" error:

```
libtbb.so.2: undefined reference to `__cxa_init_primary_exception@CXXABI_1.3.11'
```

When I checked the symbols in my libstdc++ library I saw the following

```
nm -CD libstdc++.so.6.0.24 | grep "__cxa_init_primary_exception"
000000000008fdd8 T __cxa_init_primary_exception@@CXXABI_1.3.11
```

So the only difference between the symbol name in libstdc++.so and what libtbb.so seems to require is an additional "@" in the symbol name. Even more interesting if I type

```
nm -C libtbb.so.2 | grep "__cxa_init_primary_exception"
                 U __cxa_init_primary_exception@@CXXABI_1.3.11
```

I see that libtbb requires a symbol which actually includes a double @. What's the ratio behind this naming convention and why does the linker search for a symbol name with one @?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe related to a [known issue](https://sft.its.cern.ch/jira/browse/SPI-1063)?

It's also mentioned [here](https://alisentas.com/blog/build-opencv-in-arch/):

> ...current TBB has problems with gcc-libs, it’s compiled with gcc-libs 7.x so you will get this error if you try to build OpenCV with newest TBB

Proposed solution there:

> This is also posted here, workaround is you should install TBB 2017_20170412-1 from Arch Linux Archive. To do this, first install newest TBB and then downgrade it.

Comment: Thanks, that second link really helped fixing the issue! I downloaded an older version of libtbb (github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/tree/2020_U3) and compiled it directly on my target machine - that way the correct ABI version is used.